# Scala intelliJ indentation after period

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, auto-indent

Is there a way to cancel the automatic indentation that does this:

```
Builder()
 .withFoo()
   .withBar()
```

When I type "." for withBar it indents the line automatically. I want it to look like this:

```
 Builder()
  .withFoo()
  .withBar()
```

Without having to manually fix the indentation.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. But do `CTR: + ALT + S` (or File -> Settings), go to Editor -> Code Style -> Scala. It's all there.

Comment: It's just a wild guess but from the example I would tell that your IntelliJ tries to format indentation in multiline expression with 4 spaces, while you want to use 2. Try to put more lines, I would expect that you'd get code nicely indented line-under-line, just not the indentation you want here. If that would be the case you could try changing code style as described above. Personally though, I was never happy with how IntelliJ formatted my code, no matter how I configured it, so I had to resort to scalariform for formatting whole project for me.

Comment: it looks interesting but i need something that works inside the IDE.

Comment: Yuval which intellij are you using?

Comment: @netta I'm using IntelliJ 15.0.4

Comment: @Yuval That's the same version I'm using. Maybe it's a mac intellij vs windows issue. From your shortcuts I'm getting you're running intellij on windows.

Comment: @netta Yup, Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try going in the **Settings** (Ctrl+Alt+S), **Editor** -> **Code Style** and change the **Scheme** to **Default**

If it doesn't work make sure you are on the latest version for both Scala Plugin and Idea.

If it still doesn't work try **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

If it still still doesn't work then you might consider a reinstall of Idea.

Comment: Then it's a bug and I can't see anything else than doing a File - > Invalidate Caches / Restart..

Comment: I guess it's a bug then cause invalidate caches didn't work.